# How to calculate correlation(r) between two raster datasets in R?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have two (NPP_BEGA and ENACT_BEGA) stacked raster dataset. They have the same spatial resolution, extent and dimension. I want to run and map the correlation(r) and P-values between these two raster datasets.

```
NPP_BEGA
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 321, 401, 128721, 37  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.0375, 0.0375  (x, y)
extent     : 32.98125, 48.01875, 2.98125, 15.01875  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : NPP_BEGA_RES.tif 
names      : NPP_BEGA_RES.1, NPP_BEGA_RES.2, NPP_BEGA_RES.3, NPP_BEGA_RES.4, 
NPP_BEGA_RES.5, NPP_BEGA_RES.6, NPP_BEGA_RES.7, NPP_BEGA_RES.8, NPP_BEGA_RES.9, 
NPP_BEGA_RES.10, NPP_BEGA_RES.11, NPP_BEGA_RES.12, NPP_BEGA_RES.13, NPP_BEGA_RES.14, 
NPP_BEGA_RES.15, ... 
min values :              0,              0,              0,              0,                           
max values :          90.21,          87.39,          91.44,          91.77,                    


ENACT_BEGA
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 321, 401, 128721, 37  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.0375, 0.0375  (x, y)
extent     : 32.98125, 48.01875, 2.98125, 15.01875  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : ENACT_BEGA_RES.tif 
names      : ENACT_BEGA_RES.1, ENACT_BEGA_RES.2, ENACT_BEGA_RES.3, ENACT_BEGA_RES.4, 
ENACT_BEGA_RES.5, ENACT_BEGA_RES.6, ENACT_BEGA_RES.7, ENACT_BEGA_RES.8, 
ENACT_BEGA_RES.9, ENACT_BEGA_RES.10, ENACT_BEGA_RES.11, ENACT_BEGA_RES.12, 
ENACT_BEGA_RES.13, ENACT_BEGA_RES.14, ENACT_BEGA_RES.15, ... 
min values :                0,                0,                0,                0,                
max values :            923.8,            923.8,            491.7,            512.1,
```

This is what i tried

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
ENACT_BEGA<-brick("ENACT_BEGA_RES.tif")
NPP_BEGA<-brick("NPP_BEGA_RES.tif")
Cor<-corLocal(ENACT_BEGA,NPP_BEGA, test = T)
```

and found

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
1: In cor(x, y) : the standard deviation is zero
2: In cor(x, y) : the standard deviation is zero
50: In cor(x, y) : the standard deviation is zero
```

What is wrong with the script and how can i correct this?  Thank you so much!

Comment: You might mention data source, where it can be found.

Comment: My data source is from NMA of Ethiopia and MODIS derived NPP....it is somewhat big to upload the data.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting uploading or dropboxing, but you might put the steps you took to get the data above so that someone interested could replicate to that point, this question, does rather require data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the script. You get warnings, not errors. The warnings occur for cells when there is no standard deviation because all focal values are the same for at least one of the layers:

```
cor(c(0,0,0), c(1,2,3))
#[1] NA
#Warning message:
#In cor(c(0, 0, 0), c(1, 2, 3)) : the standard deviation is zero
```